# Threading is not working correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

Doing a threading problem and I am not sure if this is how its supposed to be or if I coded incorrectly. From what I understand, threading should have multiple methods going at the same time and because of this they should be intertwined. My code is supposed to take a single char and repeat 1000 times but instead of having different variations of the two letters it goes "a" a thousand times, then "b" a thousand times. What is my issue?

Main Method

```
import java.util.*;
public class MainThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Give me a single character: ");
        char h = answer.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Give me another single character: ");
        char a = answer.next().charAt(0);   

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(h);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(a);

        t1.start(h);
        t2.start(a);        

        answer.close(); 
    }
}
```

my Threading class

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyThread extends Thread{

    Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);

    public MyThread(char x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void Stored(char x){
        System.out.println("Type a single letter here: ");      
    }


    //modified run method 
    public void start(char x){

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            System.out.print(x);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to override the run method and not the start method

Answer (score 2):

What you have done is NOT multithreading, rather you have called the `start` method sequentially, i.e., in order to run the multiple threads parallelly, you need to override the `run()` method in your `MyThread` class.

The important point is that **`run()` method will be called by JVM automatically when you `start` the Thread**, and the code inside `run()` will be executed in parallel with the main/other threads, so override `run()` inside MyThread class as shown below:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

    private char x;

    public MyThread(char x) {
        this.x= x;
    }

    // Add run() method
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(x);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainThread class:**

```
public class MainThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Give me a single character: ");
        char h = answer.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Give me another single character: ");
        char a = answer.next().charAt(0);   

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread(h);
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread(a);

        t1.start();//this calls run() of t1 automatically
        t2.start();//this calls run() of t2 automatically        

        answer.close(); 
    }
}
```

I suggest you have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for basic understanding on how to create and start the `Thread` and how multi-threading works.

Answer (score 1):

In order to let the threads run in parallel, the `run` method needs to be implemented instead of `start`.

See the JavaDoc for `Thread.start()`:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the `run` method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current
>   thread (which returns from the call to the `start` method) and the
>   other thread (which executes its `run` method).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not guaranteed that your described behavior will never occur, even when you implement a correct multithreading. But, it shouldn't be repeatable ;)

The solution is: don't override the start() but the run() method.
The thread constructor should take the argument, the start() is called (and no new start method with an argument!) from the main, and the run() implements the job that is executed parallel. Therefore, you can access the thread's field which you set in your thread constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The error was already explained: the `start` method is being overridden instead of the `run` method. Anyway it is not recommended to extend the Thread class since you are not wanting to extend its functionality.

You just want to use a Thread, so a better approach (IMO) is to provide a Runnable to the Thread:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(h));
        t1.start();
    }
```

The Runnable (use a better Name in production code):

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final char ch;

    public MyRunnable(char theChar) {
        ch = theChar;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

*This could be improved using with Lambda, but is not the point here*

More: ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread?rq=1)